# PHP locally hosted, connecting to external resources through a proxy server

Tags: php, facebook, apache, configuration, proxy

I'm trying to do some locally hosted facebook development but I'm on a university network, and therefore all outgoing connections from my computer need to pass through our proxy server. The main problem I'm having is that I can't seem to find any documentation for setting up apache to USE a proxy server, rather than to ACT as a proxy server.

Upon thinking about this however, perhaps when I do a "cURL" request or an fopen, that apache does not perform the retrieving of data, and it is instead the PHP drivers that do this. Older versions allowed you to setup a global proxy in the PHP.ini file, but not in PHP 5.

I have to use code to actually physically set the defaults and cannot find any config files where I can set them permanently. For example, this sets up streams so fopen can function:

```
    $r_default_context = stream_context_get_default
    (
    array
        (
        'http' => array
            ( // All HTTP requests are passed through the local NTLM proxy server on port 8080.
            'proxy' => 'tcp://proxy.munged.edu:8080',
            'request_fulluri' => True,
            ),
        )
    );
```

but this will not set everything which is required as to use cURL, I have to do this:

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://proxy.munged.edu:8080");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 8080);
```

Is there anyone who knows how to set all things that require outgoing connections to use this proxy as I don't won't code that's specific to this computer (because my plan was to work on my code locally and then upload it to some webspace when it's done: the change/upload/refresh cycle is ALOT more time consuming than just that change/refresh cycle)

edit:

just to clarify, i have been including all this in a file called "proxyconfig.php" then checking for it's existance, and include()-ing it at the top. if there's no way to set up the defaults in config files, having the methods to set up all the things that the facebook.php page used for their API requires would be awesom.

Comment: im not sure this is possible as facebook requires a callback to your server and unless your server is connectable through the proxy & firewall it will fail regardless of outgoing hacks

Comment: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=6461

I found this very useful topic on the facebook forum regarding it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is correct, assuming that the application is in iframe mode (FBML applications require Facebook being able to callback to your server).

If the issue is wanting to be able to develop  locally and deploy to a remote site with minimal modification to your files, I'd recommend extending **BaseFacebook** as a new class called LocalBaseFacebook and changing CURL_OPTS to:

```
public static $CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 10,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'facebook-php-3.0',
    CURLOPT_PROXY          => 'http://proxy.munged.edu:8080',
    CURLOPT_PROXYPORT      => 8080
);
```

When deploying out, make a switch when instantiating the Facebook class based on hostname or some uniquely identifying property / configuration (you could even use a $_GET variable such as ?is_local=1) and attach that to the end of your Canvas URL.